# SELECT E UPDATE - Undefined index ao submeter formulário

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Olá

Estou a construir um gestor de conteúdos e tenho uma página onde retorno os resultados do país escolhido, para que possa depois fazer o update de cada campo.

Ao escolher cada país na página Paises.php, envio o respectivo parametro para a página edit-Paises.php. Os resultados de cada coluna aparecem normalmente e até aqui tudo bem. O problema é quando submeto o formulário obtenho o erro seguinte:

> Notice: Undefined index: edit in C:\xampp\htdocs\BackOffice\edit-Paises.php on line 5

Eis o codigo da página edit-Paises.php

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';
include 'constants.php';

$edit = $_GET['edit'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT country_id, country_name, flag_file, 
header_img, intro FROM countries WHERE country_id = ? ORDER BY country_id");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $edit);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $countryName, $flag, $headerIMG, $intro);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->fetch()) {
if(!$stmt) {
    echo "Failed to execute: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
}     
$stmt->close();
}

//Form for the country update    
$paisError = "";
$flagError = "";
$imgError = "";
$introError = "";
$contError = "";

$update_country = $_GET['edit'];

if(isset($_POST['btnEdit'])) {

$país = $_POST['país'];
$intro = $_POST['intro'];
$continente = $_POST['continente'];
$bandeira = $_POST['bandeira'];
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];

if(empty($país)) {
    $paisError = "Insira um país";
} elseif(empty($intro)) {
    $introError = "Insira uma descrição";
} elseif(empty($continente)) {
    $contError = "Escolha o respectivo continente";
}  elseif(empty($bandeira)) {
    $flagError = "Insira uma bandeira";
}  elseif(empty($imagem)) {
    $imgError = "Insira uma imagem";
}  else {

$stmt_update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `countries` SET `country_name` = ?, `id_continentes` = ?, `flag_file` = ?, `header_img` = ?, `intro` = ? WHERE `country_id` = '".$_GET['edit']."' ");
$stmt_update->bind_param('s', $update_country);
$stmt_update->execute();

if(!$stmt_update) {
    echo "Failed to execute: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
}     
$stmt->close();
header('Location: thankyou.php');
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Países</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/imgPrev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/editPais.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include_once 'Menu.php';
    ?>
    <h1 id="heading">Editar País</h1>
        <form action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
            <div class="editContent">
            <label for="Pais">País</label>
            <input type="text" name="país" value="<?php echo $countryName; ?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $paisError; ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="editContent">
            <label for="Pais">Continente</label>
            <select type="text" name="continente">
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM continentes ORDER BY id";
                $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                     echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['continente'].'</option>';
                          }
                ?>
            </select>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $contError; ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="editContent">
            <label for="Pais">Bandeira</label>
            <img id="img-A" src="<?php echo $site_root;?>/images/16/<?php echo $flag; ?>"/>
            <input type="file" id="imgInp" name="bandeira">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $flagError; ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="editContent">
            <label for="Pais">Imagem País</label>
            <img id="img-B" src="<?php echo $site_root;?>/images/country_header_images/<?php echo $headerIMG; ?>"/>
            <input type="file" id="imgP" name="imagem">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $imgError; ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="editContent">
            <label for="Pais">Texto Intro</label>
            <textarea name="intro" rows="5"><?php echo $intro;  ?></textarea>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $introError; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="editContent">
            <button type="submit" id="btn_edit" name="btnEdit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>         
</body>
```

A variável $edit retorna os dados do respectivo país. Porque aparece este erro se não está envolvida na submissão do formulário?

**Edit**

Passo o parametro 'edit' através deste bloco de código na página Paises.php:

```
<?php
         $query = "SELECT country_id, country_name FROM countries ORDER BY country_name";
         $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
             echo '<tr><td cols="4">No rows returned</td></tr>';
         } else {
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             echo '<tr><td>- '.$row['country_name'].'</td><td><a href="edit-Paises.php?edit='.$row['country_id'].'">Edit</a>|<a href="">Delete</a></td></tr>';
                }
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: Eu não vejo em nenhum canto você definindo o valor do parâmetro `edit`. Nem no _form_ nem como query param.

Comment: Eu vi: `país` (com acento mesmo), `continente`, `bandeira`, `imagem` e `intro`. Todos parâmetros passados pelo formulário

Comment: Caro @JeffersonQuesado editei a minha pergunta em cima. O parametro edit vêm da página Paises.php, para mostrar os resultados em editPaises.php. Até aqui tudo bem, menos quando envio o formulário.

Comment: Qual o link que o `form` direciona? Eu particularmente não sei o que o `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` retorna. Se ele retornar apenas o caminho, sem o query param que é passado pela página anterior, então temos que o parâmetro `$_GET` só é preenchido na primeira vez que você abre a página, mas não ao submeter ao formulário. Por isso disse que não via o preenchimento do `$_GET` através do seu formulário

Comment: Uma alternativa que eu vi em alguns projetos JSP (e que poderia ser usada no seu projeto) é o formulário ser submetido para uma URL que fará a tratativa dos dados, com as possíveis inserções em banco, para então redirecionar para a página de sucesso ou de erro (ou, de sucesso e erro forem a mesma página, passar os parâmetros adequados para a apresentação dela)

Comment: Já fiz isso de colocar o processamento do formulário noutra página mas ao submeter o formulário a página retorna branco. Provavelmente não estou a fazer bem esta linha da minha query: "WHERE country_id = ?" Terei de identificar uma forma de o codigo reconhecer qual pais está a editar.

Comment: Em relação ao action do form, o $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] é para continuar na mesma página e processar o formulário.

Comment: "O problema é quando submeto o formulário obtenho o erro seguinte", a resposta é: como você não salva o `$_GET['edit']` em nenhum lugar, ao submeter novamente o formulário no método POST, o conteúdo de edit não existe mais, assim existe um indice indefinido. Para resolver isso, você pode tratar usando um `IF isset($_GET['edit'])` ou enviar novamente pelo Formulário via `POST`, assim o conteúdo deve ser recuperado através do `$_POST['edit']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema esta ocorrendo, pois na primeira vez que você chama o script você esta passando o id do pais através do atributo `edit` na URL, porém ao chamar o script novamente par atualizar os dados, no action do seu form o atributo edit não esta sendo enviado, pois a propriedade `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` retorna apenas o nome do script, e não os atributos da URI.

Substitua o **action** do seu form da seguinte forma:

`action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"`

por

`action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>"`

Comment: Caro @Ruhan O.B já tinha feito essa alteração antes. Na primeira opção, os erros continuam e na 2ª quando busco os dados através de $_POST, estes não aparecem...só aparece o formulário vazio.

Comment: Provavelmente o erro esta continuando pois ao chamar a pagina pela primeira vez o indice `$_GET['edit']` ainda não existe, neste caso basta você verificar se ele existe antes de utilizar, através da funca isset, assim não acusara de erro.

Comment: Ao fazer isset, por algum motivo retorna sempre a linha 1 da tabela, ou seja, neste caso, retorna sempre os resultados de Austria.

Comment: Este problema esta ocorrendo, pois na primeira vez que você chama o script você esta passando o id do pais através do atributo `edit` na URL, porém no action do seu form o atributo `edit ` não esta sendo enviado, pois a propriedade `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` retorna apenas o nome do script, e não os atributos da URI. Tente substituir `action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"` por `action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>"`

Comment: Assim o Notice desaparece, mesmo sem o codigo que postei acima na resposta ao @Luiz . Entretanto a submissão do formulário está a entrar no bloco da validação de erros por algum motivo, que terei agora que verificar.

Comment: Ok, já consigo fazer update aos dados. Caro Ruhan, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: As alterações que eu lhe sugeri resolveram o problema, ou foi algo diferente que você utilizou? Me informe para que eu posso editar minha resposta com solução correta.

Comment: Resolveu sim. Quanto ao update de dados, esqueci-me de colocar na UPDATE query a variavel $_GET['edit] na clausula WHERE. Antes tinha "?" e assim identifica qual a linha(ou país) a editar. Pode ver a QUERY na minha pergunta.

Comment: Entendi, vou editar a minha resposta então para que você possa marcar a resposta e ajudar outra pessoa com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Do mesmo jeito que você fez:

```
<input type="text" name="país" value="<?php echo $countryName; ?>">
```

tem de ser feito um:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cod_pais" value="<?= $_GET['edit']; ?>">
<!-- note que mudei o type de text para hidden, pois não precisa exibir-->
```

Fazendo isso, quando submeter o formulário, também haver o `$_POST['cod_pais']` que é o mesmo que o `$_GET['edit´]`... e notei aqui agora também que você colocou o name **país** com acento. Isso não é uma boa prática, usar acentuação.

Daí em diante, acho que já deu pra sacar o que tem de fazer né.

Comment: Caro @Luiz , o erro continua a aparecer mesmo colocando @. Tal como respondi acima, mesmo que altere o método de envio de formulário para GET, os erros continuam a aparecer e os dados não são enviados.

Comment: Vou refazer minha resposta, mas para isso, você tem de me dizer qual o nome do parâmetro que voce envia ao `edit-Paises.php`. Você tem que setar o codigo do país escolhido em algum dos inputs no formulário e isso você não fez pelo que vi.

Comment: Já editei a minha pergunta acima com o codigo de onde provem o parametro 'edit'. Entretanto coloquei o input hidden que você disse mas acaba por retornar a mesma mensagem de undefined index da variável $_GET['edit'] referente à linha onde está o input.

Comment: Colocando esta linha de codigo: if(isset($_GET['edit'])) { $edit = $_GET['edit']; } o erro desaparece. O problema é que os dados não estão a ser actualizados. Editei a minha query acima.